# Does jQuery.each evaluate the collection expression in every iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like:

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data).content,function(){});
```

I would like to know if the `$.parseJSON(data).content` will be evaluated on each iteration, or just once? This will affect the performance significantly.

Comment: Both the object and the number of iterations are cached, but it does use `obj[i]` or `i in obj` to look up each value, like any other loop would. You can figure out for youself how it works by reading [the source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js).

Comment: Source location: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/core.js#L591

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments of a function call are always evaluated before the function is called. This isn't jQuery specific. See [the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.3):

> 3 . Let argList be the result of **evaluating `Arguments`**, producing an internal list of argument values (see 11.2.4).
>
> ...
>
> 8 . Return the result of **calling the [[Call]] internal method on `func`**, providing `thisValue` as the this value and providing the list `argList` as the argument values.

---

For clarity, this is **not** the case in `for` loops:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $.parseJSON(data).content.length; i++) {

}
```

Here, the second expression is evaluated every time. This makes sense, since in a simple loop you want to reevaluate the condition `i < length` at every iteration. But you *don't* want to run `$.parseJSON` at every iteration. So in `for` loops, it does make sense to factor out the expression.

Answer (score 2):

It is only evaluated **once**.

You can test this yourself in the javascript console:

```
    var ary = [1,2,3,4],
        getAry = function() { 
            console.log('ok'); 
            return ary; 
        };

$.each(getAry(), function(idx, val) {});
```

`"ok"` will be printed once.